# Getting the children of an element with an attribute directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that is restricted to attribute. I want to do either of 2 things. If a certain condition is met, I want to use the children for the element with the directive attribute as the model (thats the content) or if that condition is not met then I want to data bind from a service instead, so the directive would replace the children with something i was given. I have a directive that is doing the latter but Im finding it very hard to have it grab the children before the compiler comes in and replaces it with its template... Anyone know how this is done if its possible?

Comment: can you provide the code example

Comment: Ok here is a construed example of the concept. I have an attribute directive that makes the element its on a special data driven control. It goes to a service and asks for the actual content it will display and any markup or children will be replaced. 
The markup looks like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/zDva4fs9UieI4Jwlgt57 

However if the service replies with no data, then I want the directive to revert to using the actual markup on the page (pre-angular compile), so the directive will grab that <p> element and stick that in the model instead. Kind of like transclude but I want it in the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `element.context` in your directive's `link` (or `compile`) function.

Inside your `link` function (`pre` or `post`), the original element that your directive was found on is stored in the passed-in element's `context` property. So if your service call returns no data, you can just replace the compiled element with the original element by doing `element.replaceWith(element.context)`.

So your directive would look something like this:

```
.directive('ttContent', ['mySvc', function (mySvc) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    template: '<div class="content new-content" ng-bind-html="htmlContent | sanitize"></div>',
    scope: {
      testDataReturned: '@'
    },
    link: {
      pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      },
      post: function (scope, element, attrs){
        mySvc.fetchContent().then(function success(data){
            if (data) {
              scope.htmlContent = data;
            } else {
              // element.context is our original, pre-compiled element
              element.replaceWith(element.context);
            }
          }, function fail(data){
            element.replaceWith(element.context);
        });
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNxTHq0lOnFsrjRMBIHg).

Comment: MikeJ, You sir are my hero :D